# How do I insert page numbers in Libreoffice? Microsoft-Office style

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I have fully switched from Ms Office suite to LibreOffice however one thing I really miss about office is how it handled page numbering. All I had to do was just click on the insert bar and simply choose page number option and then voila Office would automatically insert the page numbers in the position I want it to be. How can I get such functionality in LibreOffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this link for instructions on inserting page numbers! 
https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Inserting_Page_Numbers_in_Footers

Comment: Thanks it certainly does the job but not as effortless as the manner in which Office handles this operation

Comment: If you have problem with page number starting from 1 in the middle of the document try saving, close and reopening. It's a bug. [Here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/36592/why-does-page-numbering-restart-at-1-in-the-middle-of-my-document/) you could find more info.